# Get CPU usage and CPU memory consumption from flash?

Tags: flash, apache-flex

Hi guys is there any way i can get CPU usage and CPU memory usage details in flex? 
I know that flash can't access any system resources. But is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

don't know how to access cpu stats, however it's possible to monitor memory using [`flash.system.System`](http://help.adobe.com//en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html) class

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has a task manager which isolates cpu and memory usage for flash. But make sure there's no other flash running in any other tabs.